# Question about direct product of two groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $d=p^k$ for some prime $p$ such that $d$ divides both $n$ and $m$. Then $G$ has exactly $d\phi(d)+[d-\phi(d)]\phi(d)$.

For example consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ here $d=p^k$ is $4=2^2$ and $4$ divides $n=4$ and $m=4$ so using above formula we have there are $12$ elements of order $4$.

If we have a group $G$ such as $G=\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, then $G$ has $6$ elements of order $6$ and the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$  has $24$ elements of order $6$.

Is there any formula for counting number of elements of a specific order in later two groups?

Comment: If you look at the proof of the first mentioned formula, you should be able to see how to handle other cases (note that you do not need the order to be a prime power for the formula to work).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for your hint finally I got it.